# Accessing Minio with a self signed certificate and the Python client library

Tags: python, python-3.x, minio, urllib3

We have an instance of minio running with a certificate that is signed by our corporate CA. Accessing it with S3 Browser works perfect. Now I try to write a python script to upload files. I try to use the windows cert store to get my CA certs

```
myssl = ssl.create_default_context()

myhttpclient = urllib3.PoolManager(
      cert_reqs='CERT_REQUIRED',
      ca_certs=myssl.get_ca_certs()
)

s3dev = Minio("s3dev.mycorp.com:9000,
     access_key="myAccessKey",
     secret_key="mySecretKey"
     secure=True,
     http_client=myhttpclient
)
```

I get an error "TypeError: unhashable type: list"

Getting the CA Certs from Windows cert store with ssl.get_ca_certs() returns a list with all the certs in it which seems logic to me, what am I missing here to get something this simple to work ?

Comment: Please update your question to show the full traceback for the `TypeError` exception.

Comment: Although according to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext.load_cert_chain), if `ca_certs` is specified, it should be a path to a file containing a list of root certificates, not a list of certificates.

Comment: @larsks I saw that now as well, however I think it would be good if urllib3 would support the native cert stores on the different OS. I made a feature request https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/2886 for that now. As I workaround I exported the needed CA cert as .pem file and it worked now.